# How to change monitor resolution in my case?

Tags: 14.04, display-resolution

When I put xrandr I got

```
milenko@milenko-X58-USB3:~$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1400 x 1050, current 1400 x 1050, maximum 1400 x 1050
default connected primary 1400x1050+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1400x1050      77.0* 
  1680x1050_60.00 (0x1bf)  146.2MHz
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock   65.3KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock   60.0Hz
```

What means failed to get size of gamma?How to solve this?
My card

```
inxi -G
Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430] 
           X.Org: 1.15.1 drivers: fbdev,ati,radeon (unloaded: vesa) Resolution: 1400x1050@77.0hz 
           GLX Renderer: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 3.4, 128 bits) GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 10.1.3
```

My video driver

```
root@milenko-X58-USB3:~# lshw -c video
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fbdc0000-fbddffff ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fbd00000-fbd1ffff
```

Comment: @DevRobot Is there any other way?

Comment: Have you tried to add the output of `cvt` to your `xorg.conf` file  ?

Comment: you can't expect to change the resolution of your screen by just running xrandr, you need to give more parameters, such as --addmode, connection type and the resolution you want. And by the way, if you don't installed proper drivers (ATI in your case) you will never be able to change the resolution as the basic drivers have basic resolutions...

Comment: @ostendali the `gamma failed` error indicates that no xrandr commands will work...

Comment: @Harris simply adding `cvt` output to `xorg,conf` won't change anything - all the OP entered was `xrandr` - so that won't change anything

Comment: @DevRobot that is correct, but see/read the rest of my comment about the drivers:-) this link provides enough information to install correctly the drivers: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver. if xrandr si not working it is clearly driver related

Comment: @ostendali yes, you should try installing the drivers - but if they still don't give you the suitable resolutions, then it's still a problem. Even if drivers are installed that give the right resolution, `gamma failed` errors at the `xrandr` command show that even then, you won't able to select the resolution.

Comment: @DevRobot if you run `cvt 1680 1050 60` it will produce a Modeline code that you can add to the 'xorg.conf' file in the monitor section. In my case it produces `Modeline "1680x1050_60.00"  146.25  1680 1784 1960 2240  1050 1053 1059 1089 -hsync +vsync`.

Comment: @Harris yes, but you run the command `xrandr` to check if it's working correctly. The error the OP gets proves it isn't. Since there isn't a solution, then we can probably say that `xrandr` is useless on his system

Comment: @DevRobot, ok I got your point.

Comment: @DevRobot Take a look at my video driver,should I change this?

Comment: @Harris
The link you have provided is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you can do here, but you can try setting the gamma of display with `xrandr`.

First find your monitor name with `xrandr | grep " connected " | awk '{ print$1 }`.

Now enter the `xrandr` command:

```
xrandr --output monitor_name --gamma 1:1:1
```

Now entering `xrandr` again.